# Exporting checkbox data to excel using jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have an `<ASP:GridView>` with few columns with boolean values returned from SQL Server. I am using datatables plugin looks good but when I export the data to Excel, all are exporting to Excel except the `bool` values that show empty.

Here is my simple jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excel'
            ]
        });
    });
```

I have tried as stated in the link https://m.datatables.net/forums/discussion/45691/excelhtml5-how-to-export-checkbox-data but in vain.

Tried code 1

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        var i = $(data).prop("checked")===true?"Yes":"No";
                        return i;
                    },
                    "targets": [1,2,13,16,17,19]
                }
            ]
```

It displays "NO" even bool col value is true.

Tried code 2

```
buttons: [            
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
        }
    ]
```

Tried code 3

```
buttons: [            
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
        }
    ]
```

Any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this return: `$(data).prop("checked")`

Comment: It returns "No", even for bool value 1.

Comment: It cannot return *No*. It can only return `true` or `false`. Please read my question carefully cuz I am only asking about `$(data).prop("checked")`

Comment: $(data).prop("checked") returns 'false' and var i contains 'No'

Comment: So should it not be retuning `false`? I do not have access to `data` and you did not post it so I cannot tell.

Comment: I have created a fiddle based on server generated html file. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/nuzontt8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the `DataTable` plugin, but we are developer so let's go figure out the issue. You created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuzontt8/1/) and the important bit in your HTML is this:

```
  <td>72</td>
  <td><span class="aspNetDisabled" title="Is Credit"><input id="CentreContent_GridView1_ctl00_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CentreContent$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00" disabled="disabled" /></span></td>
  <td><span class="aspNetDisabled" title="Is Quotation"><input id="CentreContent_GridView1_ctl01_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$CentreContent$GridView1$ctl02$ctl01" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span></td>
```

You have three `td` tags so you have 3 columns. Here is what the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for the plugin says about if you were to provide a function for `render`:

> If a function is given, it will be executed whenever DataTables needs to get the data for a cell in the column.

This is your callback function:

```
function (data, type, row){
    var i = $(data).prop("checked")===true?"Yes":"No";
    return i;
}
```

So basically it will call your function with three arguments. The argument we are interested in (for your question) is `data`. The `data` parameter will contain the html for the cell so you can do some decision making based on its contents. Since your HTML for cell has this structure

```
<td><span><input></span></td>
```

then when you do `$(data)`, JQuery will select all of the HTML and then look for the `checked` attribute but obviously that will not work. You have to specifically tell JQuery which element to select and then look for the attribute. Therefore, your code need to be like this:

```
var $element = $(data).find(':input')
var i;
if ($element && $element.is(':checkbox')) {
    i = $element.prop('checked') === true ? "Yes" : "No";
} 
else {
    // What will you do if not checkbox?
}
```

Now we are specifically looking for an `input` element which is a checkbox and checking if the checkbox is checked.

[¯_(ツ)_/¯ Here is the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/637/)